# How to use gcc -I on Windows?

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64

I'm using gcc from mingw compiler. When I try to add folder for external library using `gcc -I`, I couldn't include those header files.

My command looks like this: `gcc -I "C:\Program Files\Mosquitto\devel\" .\mqtt-c.c`

This is the error:
`gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.`

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Windows Powershell

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, please make sure you post your exact command and its entire output (format everything as a code block).

Comment: Avoid spaces in paths when using MinGW.